# What is the correct way to use send() on sockets when the full message has not been sent in one go?

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a simple C server that may sometimes not send nor receive the full message. I have looked at [the beej guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#sendrecv) and the [linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) among other resources. I cannot figure out how I can send and receive when multiple send and receive calls are necessary. This is what I have tried to do for send:

```
char* buffer [4096];
int client_socket, buffer_len, message_len, position;
....
while (position < message_len) {
    position = send(client_socket, buffer, message_len, 0);
}
```

I am not sure if I should be doing that or..

```
while (position < message_len) {
    position = send(client_socket, buffer+position, message_len-position, 0);
}
```

**The docs do not address this** and I cannot find a usage example that has send within a while loop. Some C functions can track state between function calls (such as strtok) but I am not sure if send does. What I don't want to do is repeatedly send from the beginning of the message until it completes in one go.

It is necessary that I send files that are up to 50MB at a time and so there will likely be more than one call to send in this scenario.

Comment: Also:you should realize that `send()` can return -1 or 0.

Answer (score 4):

`send()` returns the number of bytes sent, or -1 if an error occurred. If you keep track of how many bytes you have sent, you can use that as an offset in the buffer you send from. The length of the message that remains to be sent of course decreases by the same amount.

```
int bytes_sent_total = 0;
int bytes_sent_now = 0;
while (bytes_sent_total < message_len)
{
    bytes_sent_now = send(client_socket, &buffer[bytes_sent_total], message_len - bytes_sent_total, 0);
    if (bytes_sent_now == -1)
    {
        // Handle error
        break;
    }
    bytes_sent_total += bytes_sent_now;
}
```

Comment: thank you, what about recv? Does recv work in the same way in that you must adjust the pointer to the buffer and buffer size remaining?

Comment: @Aorona Yes, `recv` will work in practically the same way as long as you know how much data to expect. (JL Sanchez's answer brings up some good points about this)

Comment: the function: `send()` has a returned value with type: `ssize_t` not `int`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a stream socket (not specified), in fact it doesn't matter how many calls to the 'send' function your program will do. The socket library offers the abstraction of sending data as writing to a file. The network layer will divide the data into small packets for sending them through the net.

On the client side, the network layer reassembles the received packets and offers a similar abstraction for the client, so that receiving data is like reading from a file. So you don't have to read the entire buffer in a single call.

For the client side, this introduces a small gimmick: when to stop reading? Common idioms are:

- Knowing beforehand how much data to expect (by protocol design).
- Iterating reads of small chunks (say: 1k or so) with a reasonable timeout, stop on timeout.
- Prepending the data with a field containing its size.
- Closing the socket right after sending the data (that's what HTTP usually does).